# javascript - cancel awaited function before it is called again

Tags: javascript

On incoming webrtc call, I open a modal to show user a message about media permissions and `await` this till the user presses OK button on the modal.

I do it like this:

```
async function myMessage(){
    $('#id_my_message_modal').modal('show');
    return new Promise(resolve => 
        $('#id_my_message_button').on('click', () => {
                $('#id_my_message_modal').modal('hide');
                resolve();
            }
        )
    );
}
```

then

```
await myMessage();
```

The issue I am facing now is if `await myMessage();` is called again while the previous call has still not returned(i.e user hasn't pressed OK button). I want a way to cancel any previous `await myMessage();`, if exists, before it is called again.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: No, nothing exists in the language. You need to do it yourself. What does cancellation mean to you, hiding the modal and rejecting the promise? Then do that.

Comment: Can you give me a code example how promise rejection would fit in my case?

Comment: Why don't you think it would fit? If it doesn't, then don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach ([Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-modal-queue-5yerp?file=/src/index.js))- add every call of the async function to the queue, so you will get a sequence of dialogs with the result returning (close/accept/whatever).

```
// decorator from my other answer
function asyncBottleneck(fn, concurrency = 1) {
  const queue = [];
  let pending = 0;
  return async (...args) => {
    if (pending === concurrency) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => queue.push(resolve));
    }

    pending++;

    return fn(...args).then((value) => {
      pending--;
      queue.length && queue.shift()();
      return value;
    });
  };
}

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const myMessage = asyncBottleneck(async function () {
  const $modal = $("#id_my_message_modal");
  $modal.modal("show");
  const result = await new Promise((resolve) =>
    $modal.on("click", "button", (e) => {
      $modal.modal("hide");
      $modal.off("click", "button");
      resolve($(e.target).data("action"));
    })
  );
  await delay(250);
  return result;
});
```

The second approach ([Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-agnesi-8jpu0?file=/src/index.js))- multiplexing the fn calls, when every await of the function will return the same result; Compare console output of the live demos.

```
function singleThread(fn) {
  let promise = null;

  return function (...args) {
    return (
      promise ||
      (promise = fn(...args).finally(() => {
        promise = null;
      }))
    );
  };
}

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const myMessage = singleThread(async function () {
  const $modal = $("#id_my_message_modal");
  $modal.modal("show");
  const result = await new Promise((resolve) =>
    $modal.on("click", "button", (e) => {
      $modal.modal("hide");
      $modal.off("click", "button");
      resolve($(e.target).data("action"));
    })
  );
  await delay(250);
  return result;
});

$("#btn-run").on("click", async () => {
  myMessage().then((c) => console.log(`First result: ${c}`));
  await myMessage().then((c) => console.log(`Second result: ${c}`));

  myMessage().then((c) => console.log(`Third result: ${c}`));
});
```

The third way- closing the previous modal with its promise rejecting ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-modal-singlethread-forked-byn5n?file=/src/index.js) open console there to see the result).

```
import CPromise from "c-promise2";

const showModal = (() => {
  let prev;
  return (id, text = "") => {
    prev && prev.cancel();

    return (prev = new CPromise((resolve, reject, { onCancel }) => {
      const $modal = $(id);

      text && $modal.find(".modal-body").text(text);

      $modal.modal("show");

      const dispose = () => {
        $modal.modal("hide");
        $modal.off("click", "button");
      };

      $modal.on("click", "button", function (e) {
        dispose();
        resolve($(this).data("action"));
      });

      $modal.on("hidden.bs.modal", () => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("close"));
      });

      onCancel(dispose);
    })).finally(() => (prev = null));
  };
})();

$("#btn-run").on("click", async () => {
  showModal("#id_my_message_modal", "First message").then(
    (c) => console.log(`First modal result: ${c}`),
    (e) => console.warn(`First modal fail: ${e}`)
  );
  showModal("#id_my_message_modal", "Second message").then(
    (c) => console.log(`Second modal result: ${c}`),
    (e) => console.warn(`Second modal fail: ${e}`)
  );

  const promise = showModal("#id_my_message_modal", "Third message")
    .then(
      (c) => console.log(`Third modal result: ${c}`),
      (e) => console.warn(`Third modal fail: ${e}`)
    )
    .timeout(5000)
    .then(() => {
      return showModal(
        "#id_my_message_modal2",
        "Blue Pill or Red Pill?"
      ).then((v) => console.log(`Pill: ${v}`));
    });

  /*setTimeout(()=>{
    promise.cancel(); you can cancel the modal from your code 
  }, 1000);*/
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (pending >= concurrency)`? Also, don't forget to remove the click handler.

Comment: @DavidKnipe No, it shouldn't- the pending value is always less or equal to the concurrency const. In this case, it can be 0 or 1. As far listener removing, you're definitely right.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I get this error `ncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).once is not a function`

Comment: @Newbie just replace `once` with `one`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah I did that. Thanks. But there is an issue. Here is what happens. call `myMessage()` -> modal opens. call `myMessage()` again --> modal is still open --> press OK --> modal closes. call `myMessage()` -- > modal does not open. I would like the modal to open, if it isn't already, any number of time `myMessage()` is called. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: If modal is closed everytime after I call `myMessage()` then it will reopen in next `myMessage()` call. That is fine. But the above said issue remains

Comment: @Newbie Added live demos for each approach.

Comment: @DmitriyMozgovoy I really appreciate your time to help me. I am using your first demo. What changes should I make so that there is only one modal open no matter how many times `myMessages()` is called, of course with cancelling ability.I tried closing modal before showing it again in the `myMessage()` call. But that doesn't seem to work. I am trying to have only latest and only one `myMessage()` which also means only one modal open(from latest call).

Comment: Ok. I got it working. I used a flag to avoid opening multiple instances of the  modal. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Newbie if you need to dismiss and reject the promise of the previous modal before showing another, you can use the third approach that I just added.